# How to complete the list of attributes to be the same as parent's

Tags: t-sql

I have a Regulations table with state and county regulations:

```
    RegID   State   County  RegulationName Regulation   
    1       CA              weight         10 pounds    
    1       CA              distance       20 miles 
    2       CA      Orange  distance       22 miles
```

The parent (state) has statewide regulations, ex. weight and distance.

The children (counties) may overwrite some of the regulations. In this example Orange county overwrites state regulation “distance” with its own value 22 miles.

The  “weight” regulation for the Orange county is not listed in the table. Because it implies that Orange county uses parent’s “weight”

What is the way to always show the full list of all regulations on a county level? To return implied state level regulation that was not overwritten at the county level. 
For Example:

```
    RegId   State   County  RegulationName Regulation
    1       CA              weight         10 pounds    
    1       CA              distance       20 miles
    2       CA      Orange  weight         10 pounds 
    2       CA      Orange  distance       22 miles
```

Comment: When a value is superseded by a more local regulation, is the winning value always the minimum or maximum, or simply the more local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it is a simple case of the County regulations supersede State regulations regardless of the values involved:

```
declare @Regulations as Table ( RegulationId Int Identity, RegId Int, State VarChar(2),
  County VarChar(16), RegulationName VarChar(16), Regulation VarChar(16) );

insert into @Regulations ( RegId, State, County, RegulationName, Regulation ) values
  ( 1, 'CA', NULL, 'weight', '10 pounds' ),
  ( 1, 'CA', NULL, 'distance', '20 miles' ),
  ( 2, 'CA', 'Orange', 'distance', '22 miles' ),
  ( 3, 'NY', NULL, 'weight', '1 stone' ),
  ( 4, 'NY', 'NYC', 'weight', '16 grams' ),
  ( 5, 'ND', NULL, 'shoe size', '9E' );

select * from @Regulations;

-- Start with all of the explicitly stated regulations.
select RegId, State, County, RegulationName, Regulation, 'Explicit' as [Type]
  from @Regulations
union all
-- Then add all of the missing county level regulations.
select L.RegId, L.State, C.County, L.RegulationName, L.Regulation, 'Implicit'
  from @Regulations as L cross join
    ( select distinct County, State from @Regulations where County is not NULL ) as C left outer join
    @Regulations as R on R.State = L.State and R.County = C.County and R.RegulationName = L.RegulationName
  -- Where the regulation applies at the state level (L.County is NULL) and
  --   there is no matching county level row (R.County is NULL from the LEFT OUTER JOIN).
  where L.County is NULL and R.County is NULL and C.State = L.State
  order by State, County, RegulationName;
```